# How to use BOOST_FOREACH with an Unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, unordered-map

OK, so here's my situation - pretty straightforward but I'm not sure how it can work (I can find no documentation whatsoever...) :

I have an `Unordered_map` :

```
typedef unsigned long long U64;
typedef boost::unordered_map<U64, U64> HASH;
```

And I would like to loop through the elements (mainly the keys), pretty much like using PHP `foreach`, but this time using `BOOST_FOREACH`, I suspect something like :

```
HASH myMap;

// .. assignment, etc...

BOOST_FOREACH (U64 key, myMap)
{
     // do sth with the Key-Value pair

     U64 val = myMap[key];
}
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each entry in the `Unordered_map` will be a pair, so when you use the map in conjuction with `BOOST_FOREACH` you will iterate over that pair like so:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( HASH::value_type& v, myMap ) {
    std::cout << "key is " << v.first << " value is " << v.second << std::endl;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just solved it :**

```
BOOST_FOREACH(HASH::value_type pair, myMap)
{
     U64 key = pair.first;
     U64 value = pair.second;
}
```